# how to replace some elements symmetrically with zero randomly?

Tags: matlab, matrix

there is a symmetric matrix A including 1 and 0 elements, as we know in such a matrix we have A(i,j)=A(j,i). I wanna replace randomly an exact fraction of 1 elements with 0 symmetrically in matlab. I mean if element A(i,j) is randomly chosen to be replaced with 0, then element A(j,i) would be replaced with 0 simoltaneously. so is there any way to do something like this in matlab?

Comment: you could always work on one half of the matrix, one you're finished, make it symmetric again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's an mxn matrix (m = n) and you want to replace k elements, you could do:

```
%Find the indeces for the elements equal to 1
[onesX, onesY] = find(A == 1);
numOnesX = size(onesX,1);
numOnesY = size(onesY,1); % numOnesX and numOnesY should be the same

%Generate a random set of elements to be replaced
xRep = randperm(numOnesX);
xRep = onesX(xRep(1:k));
yRep = randperm(numOnesY);
yRep = onesY(yRep(1:k));

%Do the replacement
A(xRep, yRep) = ~A(xRep, yRep);
A(yRep, xRep) = ~A(yRep, xRep);
```

Answer (score 0):

if adj is the matrix containing ones and zeros, then create the symmetric matrix:

```
adj = adj + adj';
adj(adj>1)=1;
```

use this matrix to index for replacements